Can you add poison to breath weapon?
My goal is to find a way to add poison to a breath weapon to make it eligible for Venomfire.
4 possibilites I have yet to find a way to achieve this:

Find a way to add a dose of poison to a spell-like/supernatural
ability. (Like Poison Spell use a poison as a component of a spell
to add this particular poison to the spell. Touch only.)
Add a poison effect to the breath weapon. (Few Dragons have a breath
weapon dealing poison damage like Steel Dragons for example, but I
would like to find a regular, damage hitpoint damaging breath and
being able to add poison on top to make it eligible to venomfire...)
Find a creature with a breath weapon dealing poison damage. There is
a few poison dealing poison damage as hitpoint damage. If I remember
correctly, there is one or two creatures with a natural poison
dealing hit points damage but I can be wrong.
Finding a way to deal poison damage to hitpoints... Via a prestige
class or a template? But most sources precisely let you deal ENERGY
damage. (Breath weapon admixture, Metabolic Fire graft...)  Races of
the dragon gives you a list of most dragons eligible for the
Half-Dragon template and none of them deal poison damage.

Anything I am missing?

Highly-related question, the answers to which suggest that there are no answers to this, though I won’t go quite so far as to say it’s a duplicate. I hope you do find an answer here.

seeing as what you want speciphically might be out of reach, a build-around is possible;
SPEW!: A guide to spitting for fun and profit.
this might be an interesting read for you.
this guide describes how you can gain, and optimize a venomous spittle attack that basically functions as a breath weapon, which qualifies for venomfire.
Seeing as some of these methods described are inside the "dm's approval" realm of discussions, the most RAW indisputable way to go about this in my opinion is:
SERPENT KINGDOMS:

Spit Venom:

Turn your poisonous bite natural melee attack into a ranged contact poison (30ft)

Deadly spittle:

Turn that spit into a cone (15ft) (the prerequisite of this feat talks about having "the spit venom feat or spittle attack, spit attack,"
meaning you'd qualify with something like blinding spittle from the druid spell list (at druid level 1 if you're looking at magic of faerun for the spell level 1 version, or druid lvl 3 if you're using the 3.5 updated version of the spell at spell level 2)

Improved spit:

Double the range of your spray & increase that range by their base value every time you take this feat

two expensive ways the guide describes for qualifying for spit venom feat are:

Animal devotion

this devotion feat grants you a single use of the poisonous bite attack and one extra for every 3 turn-attempts you blow on it. this is a 1d3 CON dmg atk. (requires a level in cleric for the animal domain, before you qualify for the devotion feat, and a way to sustain turn attempts for more than one use of your natural bite attack)
Totem-bound phase cloak
two levels of totemist grants you access to this feature, a bite attack for 1d3 CON dmg with a fort save (no secondary damage) (requires two levels of totemist)

Something else to look at is the following template:
Murkdwellers: LA+0
Also in serpent kingdoms, on p.72; the description in the guide talks about 'anthropomorphic gilamonsters' which is an apt description.
they come with a spit attack and weapon finesse, as well as +6 dex on the template. i can only agree to the fact this guide calls them out to be the most suited for optimizing spit attacks, and, if you're tacking on venomfire.. full caster progression without LA or dips in other classes.

in short;
i can't imagine a way to tack on poison to a breath weapon, but you can build your own.
